# Shouldn't I git ignore cdk.out folder which is made by AWS CDK？

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitignore, aws-cdk

AWS CDK create `cdk.out` project root. I don't know if I should add git files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `cdk init app`, you see that cdk.out folder is in .gitignore.

```
*.js
!jest.config.js
*.d.ts
node_modules

# CDK asset staging directory
.cdk.staging
cdk.out
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add cdk.out to git. It just holds artifacts like synthesized cloudformation templates which do not need to be in version control.

Comment: But doesn't it also hold state?

Comment: @TheOnin you can safely delete the cdk.out content: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2869#issuecomment-607971957